# Twitter Bootstrap Google+ Login Button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-plus, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a Google+ login button to the navbar on my Twitter Bootstrap website. This requires adding some javascript, and adding the following div:

Sign In

I am adding this div in the navbar as part of a ul, as shown below:

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/about" target="_blank">About</a></li>
        <li><div id="account-login">Sign In</div></li>
      </ul>
```

How do I make the div act as an 'a' field, so it inherits the proper css properties? I have to keep it as a div to make the clicking work.

The actual url is http://instockalerts.net for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enter code here`Not sure i understand your question properly but i think what you want is the "div" tag to behave same as the "a" tag , inherit its styles etc ? , well easiest solution i can think of is to create a id specific style in your style sheet, like :

```
  #account-login {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        padding-top: 19.5px;
        padding-bottom: 19.5px;
        color: #fff;
         line-height: 21px;
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        background: transparent;
    }
```

Add hover event in a similar manner by

```
  #account-login:hover {
      color: #446cb0;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: white;
    }
```